# Nodemailer was sending mails but then it suddenly stopped, now it's giving me this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

This worked like some days ago but then it stopped. I really don't know what's going on. PS: I am on a Mac and it does not look like it's a firewall issue.

```
exports.sendEmail = (recipient, subject) => {
  const mailTransporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
      pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS
    }
  })

  const mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
    to: recipient,
    subject,
    html: htmlTemplate(generatePasswordResetLink(),recipient),
  }

  return mailTransporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, success) => {
    if (error) {
     console.log(error);
      return error;
    }
    return success;
  })
```

The `console.log(error);` in the code spits this

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 74.125.133.109:465
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1097:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '74.125.133.109',
  port: 465,
  command: 'CONN' }
```

And I have tried like everything possible to get it to work. I have also restarted my laptop.

PS:

```
user: 'a valid gmail account',
pass: 'correct pass for the account'
```

Comment: Its not able to connect to the secure SSL port `465` for the SMTP host you have provided i.e `74.125.133.109`, if you trying with gmail, then you may try replacing address with `smtp.gmail.com` and try.
incase of TLS, for gmail the port is `587`

Comment: Do your password contain special characters?

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty Thanks for your comment. I also tried that earlier (replacing the addressing with `smtp.gmail.com`), it still didn't work.

Comment: @TienDuong Thanks also for commenting. No, it's something between a-zA-Z.

Comment: did you try with `smtp.gmail.com` with port 587? what does it give? is it the same error?  and may be for 587  port, you have to make `secure :false`
if yes, then can you make sure, wherever you are running the app, its able to access internet from the server.

Comment: is your environment changed? like added any firewall or deployed to different server or something?

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty I have tried it, it gives the same error. The only difference in the error object is the port number - changes to 587.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty That's the funny thing. Everything has been on my local machine. Firewall settings still the same. Damn, this is tiring...I changed the email account, still, I got the same error.

Comment: ```mailTransporter.verify``` method returns the same error.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty @saikatchakrabortt

I switched to using 

```
 service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
      pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS
    },
```
It still didn't work that day I decided to dump the code and get back to it later. Funny thing is I tried it today and everything works fine now.

Thanks guys!

Comment: I am having the same issue. Then I tried with hard-coded username and password in the auth section of my JS file. Surprisingly it worked. Any clues how can I revert it back to reading from a file ?